# Reinitialize Combine Publishers When User Changes Global Object

Tags: core-data, swiftui, combine

I have a Core Data publisher that is working great so far. I have a `Workspace` entity and a `Project` entity. I use the following publisher to get all the projects for a given workspace:

```
class ProjectModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var projects = [Project]()
  private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

  init(){
    CoreDataPublisher(request: Project.getAllProjects(), context: PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
      .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { print($0) },
        receiveValue: { [weak self] items in
          self?.projects = items
        })
      .store(in: &cancellableSet)
  }
}
```

The fetch request `getAllProjects()` is in a Core Data entity extension here where the `NSPredicate` filters based on a `Workspace` object set in the UI.

```
//Core Data Entity Extension
extension Project{
  @nonobjc public class func getAllProjects() -> NSFetchRequest<Project> {
    let workspace = AppState.shared.workspace as Workspace //<-- The user can change this workspace
  
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Project>(entityName: "\(Self.self)")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Project.name, ascending: true)]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "workspace = %@", workspace)
    return request
  }
}
```

This `Workspace` object is in a global state class:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject{
  static let shared = AppState()
  @Published var workspace: Workspace!

  init(){
    //Setup the workspace for the first time
  }
}
```

I can successfully receive data from my publisher and I can successfully change the global `Workspace` in the UI. The problem is that after changing the `Workspace`, the publisher still points to the old `Workspace` originally set when the fetch request was created.

How do I prompt the `ProjectModel` to reinitialize in order to renew the publisher's state when the `AppState`'s `workspace` is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the way to accomplish this is to use the `flatMap` operator on your publisher. `flatMap` lets you "create a new publisher based on this received value, and then use that publisher's output as the overall publisher chain's output".

It would look something like this:

```swift
AppState.shared.$workspace.flatMap { workspace in
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Project>(entityName: "\(Project.self)")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Project.name, ascending: true)]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "workspace = %@", workspace)
    return CoreDataPublisher(request: request, context: PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
}
```

This gives you a new publisher that:

- when the `.workspace` property changes on your app state, constructs a new `CoreDataPublisher` based off whatever the new `Workspace` value is
- uses that `CoreDataPublisher` as the source of values for the overall publisher stream

Answer (score 1):

In your `ProjectModel`, I'd switch from the `Set` of `AnyCancellable` to a specific one so that you can cancel it:

```
var cdPublisherCancellable : AnyCancellable?
```

I'd move the setup of this publisher out of init, since you'll need to call it again:

```
func setupPublisher() {
  cdPublisherCancellable?.cancel()
  cdPublisherCancellable = CoreDataPublisher(request:)...
}
```

Then, since workspace is a published property on your shared AppState, I'd set up another publisher link to watch it:

```
var workspaceCancellable : AnyCancellable?
init() {
  workspaceCancellable = AppState.shared.$workspace.sink { workspace in
    setupPublisher()
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. This is essentially the same idea (as far as I can tell) as Dave's answer.

Comment: By the way, are you certain that you have to call `cdPublisherCancellable?.cancel()` prior to overwriting the same cancellable on the next line? Wouldn't that effectively replace it?

Comment: I think that you're right that publishers *should* cancel on their own deinit -- I've been preconditioned to use an abundance of caution about this type of thing (especially during the beta periods)